# Magento 2.3.4 Braintree Paypal problem / HTTPError 500

Tags: braintree

after paying with `Braintree/Paypal` sandbox I get redirected to:

> myshop.com/braintree/paypal/placeOrder/

Which gives me a HTTP error 500.

Anyone has an idea how to fix this and show the user the  order success page?

Comment: Please check the log error

Comment: Hello&Thanks, I can't find any error in my logs that would help me identify the problem unfortunately. What logs would you be checking? I tried all server logs and magento logs

Comment: I narrowed it down to disabledQuoteAddressValidation function in abstracthelper.php (vendor/magento/module-braintree/model/paypal/helper

Answer (score 0):

The problem was an invoice layout extension.